# Multi user apps

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am preparing for developing a multi-user app for Windows Phone7. But I am not able to get an example of the same. Is it possible? 
Can anyone throw some light on how to go about developing a multi-user application in Windows Phone 7?

Comment: what do you mean by "a multi-user app"?

Comment: I mean an app which can be used by two or more users - well I should have used "multi-player" apps...

Comment: This still isn't clear. There are lots of types of "multi user/player" apps. Do you want multiple players on the same device or different devices? Do they play at the same time or do they take it in turms or just compare results when finished, regardless of when they played? How many players are you talking about? Games will be very different if they have 2 players compared to games with thousands of players. Your current question is so broad as to be unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/56314.aspx